# Find a valor from list of dict

Tags: python, arrays

i have this list of dicts:

```
l = [{'campo': 'Admin_state', 'valor': 'enable'},
     {'campo': 'LinkState', 'valor': 'enable'},
     {'campo': 'ONU_interface', 'valor': 'gpon-onu_1/2/15:31'},
     {'campo': 'Profile_type_Ont', 'valor': 'ZTE-F660V3'}]
```

i need to get the valor of 'campo:LinkState' that is in the position [1], but I can not get the value through the position because it varies... So, maybe can i do something like method `.find` in Js but in python?

something like this :

```
var statusOnt = data.find(data=>data.campo=='LinkState');
```

but in python. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
l = [{'campo': 'Admin_state', 'valor': 'enable'},
     {'campo': 'LinkState', 'valor': 'enable'},
     {'campo': 'ONU_interface', 'valor': 'gpon-onu_1/2/15:31'},
     {'campo': 'Profile_type_Ont', 'valor': 'ZTE-F660V3'}]

out = next(filter(lambda d: d.get('campo', None)=='LinkState', l), {}
          ).get('valor', None)
```

output: `'enable'`

This should return None if any key is missing or value is not found.

If you want to set a default value if no dictionary matches:

```
out = next(filter(lambda d: d.get('campo', None)=='LinkState', l),
           {'valor': 'default no match'}
           ).get('valor', 'default match but no defined value')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just iterate over the `list`?

```
for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
    if (value['campo'] == 'LinkState'):
        # index is the index you wanted
        break
```

To better understand my code I would suggest you to read [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) docs.

---

If you want your code to be even more safe from `KeyError`s and `IndexError`s you can add a `try`/`catch` block:

```
try:
    if (value['campo'] ...):
        ...
except KeyError:
    continue
```

Comment: because it may crash if the key is not in the dict. Try `value.get("campo","")` - although ... his dicts all got the key so no harm.

Comment: Ok, but why should the key miss? The examples provided always contained it.